# For the function $f(x,y)=x^{2.5} \times y^{2.75},$ how do I find the directional derivative at $(5, 5)$ in the direction $θ=\frac{11π}{6}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I can't seem to get the right answer. I've been doing and redoing the problem multiple times and I keep getting about $-3308.5$
I just find the gradient and multiply it by the unit vector, but the answer is incorrect.

My work:
Calculate gradient: $<2.5*x^{1.5}*y^{2.75},2.75*x^{2.5}*y^{1.75}>$
Unit direction vector: $\langle \cos(-\pi/6),\sin(-\pi/6) \rangle$
Dot product equals to -3308.5??

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: You are being told it is incorrect by some sort of automated grading program?

Comment: Have you double checked that any calculator you are using is in radians, not degrees?

Comment: Yes it is an automated grading system, and I didn't use the calculator for doing the trig calculations. cos(-pi/6) and sin(-pi/6) doesn't need a calculator.

Comment: Sorry accidentally had a plus in place of *

Comment: Check the sign of the cosine:  $cos(-\frac{\pi}{6}) = +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: Thanks costrom. I think that was the problem, a dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $D_v=\nabla f(x,y)\cdot v=\left\|\nabla f(x,y)\right\|\left\|v\right\|\cos(\phi)$ where $\phi$ is the angle between the gradient and the given vector.